# Why does translate(-50%, -50%) work to center an element in parent but not top, left: 50%?

Tags: html, css, position

HTML:

```
<button>
<b>bold text</b>
</button>
```

Styling:

```
button {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

b {
 position:absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
  
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f436bung/

As you can see in the jsfiddle here , the text is not centered.

However, if I change the styling to this

```
b {
position:absolute;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dnkp5ywm/

It works as expected, centering the text in the middle of it's positioned parent

I'm hopefully looking for an explanation of why this is, I don't understand why top/left is not working as expected and why translate is.

Comment: none of them is supposed to center alone. You will need both.

Comment: in your specific case, translate is giving a center result due to some particular behavior of the button element so you simply had some luck. Try with another element and it won't be the case

Comment: Yes it seems to require both when using a div: https://jsfiddle.net/0ug7jpfn/ Do you know why?